# SharePoint 2013 Video live streaming

Tags: sharepoint-server, video, media-streaming

Does Sharepoint Server 2013 support live streaming of videos from other streaming servers?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

> SharePoint 2013 has a built-in HTML5 media player that is used to play all video files that are compatible with the HTML5  implementation for the current browser. This means you can now play videos on mobile devices such as iOS that don’t support Silverlight. If the format is not playable by the HTML5 player, then we use Silverlight. The video is auto-played when the user opens the video player page. The player streams video content using the BLOB cache, progressive streaming, and bit-rate throttling in the same manner as the SharePoint 2010 media player.

Ref: [Enhanced Video Experience in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.office.com/2013/03/08/enhanced-video-experience-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[image]

This also works using a simple Content Editor Web Part, where you edit the source of the webpart.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="otherserver.org/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="otherserver.org/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Ref: [HTML  src Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_src.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as noted in [this Office blog](http://blogs.office.com/2013/03/08/enhanced-video-experience-in-sharepoint-2013/) article titled "Enhanced Video Experience in SharePoint 2013":

> **Provide a link to a video**: Use this
>   option to provide a link to a video file that resides in another site
>   (such as videos from other SharePoint sites or file shares). *It is
>   important to note that your URL should point to a video stream file
>   and not to a video player URL.*
>   [emphasis added]

Answer (score 0):

No live streaming , but you can add videos wiwth correct format and turn on auto play and even optimize it with [IIS Bit Rate Throttling extension](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/bit-rate-throttling) or BLOB for smooth video streaming experiences. read more

- [Performance for video content management in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169054.asp)
- [Tips: store image, audio, or video files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-an-Asset-library-to-store-image-audio-or-video-files-96532bf6-dc72-4f82-bf0a-21ef945c4d04)

Some extracted data which shows the **Supported Video Formats** which can be played back without Silverlight. 
Note that for example not all wmv files are the same and use more popular mp4 and webm formats to have the best experience

The Media Web Part uses **HTML5 video** and supports

- asf, avi, mpg, mp3, mp4, ogg, ogv, webm, wma, and wmv video formats

The **classic Silverlight** Media Web Part supports

- asf, mp3, mp4, wma, and wmv.